# Portable WiFi Access Point with HTTP Server for File Downloads

Tags: wifi, web-server, access-point

### Functional Requirements

I need a reasonably portable device that would allow people to use their laptops to connect via WiFi and navigate to a domain name I would tell them. The domain name would serve a web page that would have links to files for download that would be hosted **on and served from** the device.

### Use-Case Requirements

My use-case is for making 1 hour presentations I would like to run like a mini-workshop so **I expect to have ~25 people connected and downloading, all at the time same time**.

#### What is the Specific Use-Case?

Basically I want give a presentation to people about how to set up an open-source local development environment for WordPress and so I need **people to be able to download the required files** to their computer **at the start of the presentation.**

#### Why These Requirements?

**WiFi Internet tends to be slow and/or unreliable** at the locations where I will be giving these presentations, and my goal is to get as many people to actually start using this local development environment I built as I possibly can so I want to ensure successful setup for as many people as possible.

### Assumed Technical Requirements

Obviously the device will need to be a **WiFi access point**, it would need provide a **web server**, **DNS server** and **DHCP server** and the domain name such as `downloads.lan` would only be visible to them when they are connected to the device.

### Non-Requirements

The device does  **NOT need an upstream connection to the Internet**. All it really needs to do is give them a special purchase WiFi access point to connect to, download files and then disconnect.

#### But Nice-to-Have

However a nice-to-have would be to have the device connect to an upstream Internet connection using DHCP -- in the case such a connection is available -- then proxy the traffic to the Internet *(except traffic to `downloads.lan`)*, assuming the device could handle lots of connections. But again, that would just be a nice-to-have, not a requirement.

### "Failed" Attempts Thus Far

So I have tried several things thus far that either did not work or that were far from optimal.

#### LibraryBox on TP-Link MR3040

My first attempt at this was to buy a [TP-Link MR3040](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0088PPFP4) and install [LibraryBox](http://librarybox.us/) software on it. Unfortunately, it took over 10 minutes to download the necessary files with only 1 computer connected; far too long. So the device **needs to be fast; i.e. have lots of bandwidth.**

#### Apple Time Capsule

I then looked at an [older Apple Time Capsule](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002TLTGGM) I have. But it does not support a web server so it would be more technical to access, and it is on the very heavy end of portable.  This may be my fall-back, but I am hoping I can find something better.

#### Ubuntu + Hostapd + Lenovo IdeaCenter Q180

I then tried to set up an old [Lenovo IdeaCenter Q180](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006THJIXI) I had laying around by installing [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/) and Hostapd, but I had a nightmare trying to get everything configured correctly all at once.

I started with Ubuntu Server but could not get it to connect to my WiFi -- which is necessary to download and install software -- so I switched to Ubuntu Desktop which has a GUI and thus I could get WiFi connected, but **I could still not figure out how to get Hostapd to work**. Evidently it needs to control the WiFi and yet Ubunutu Desktop does not want to let go of the WiFi.

I feel certain this would work if I could just figure out how to configure everything. I expect maybe I need to buy another WiFi adapter for Hostapd to use like maybe the [TP-LINK TL-WN722N](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002SZEOLG) but I don't want to go down another dead-end and I am not much more than a beginner as Linux and I may not be able to figure it out on my own.

### Summary

At this point I am **happy to spend money to solve the problem**. I am happy to buy a different device if you can point me to something that will work. *(I'd even hire someone to build it if the fee was modest!)* I just want ***something*** that will work and meet my requirements, and not take 20 hours of my time to get working.

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hostapd is hard to set up if you don't know what you are doing. I've had the same issue, I just couldn't make it work so I searched and found [this](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) beautiful script called **create_ap**. It can create a wifi network with a single command.

If that still doesn't work, you can buy some travel router (for example TP-LINK TL-WR710N, it is the first thing I found) and you can just connect your Lenovo with the router.

If you want to make it smaller, you can use [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/) as your storage server and in the best case scenario you can power it via USB that is on the router. Unfortunately, I can't find how much current does that USB have so I'm not sure if it will be enough for RPi and you will probably need a second power supply.

Raspberry Pi Model 3 does have wifi but using create_ap might not be that stable. I've tried create_ap on Orange Pi Zero (cheaper knockoff of RPi) and it didn't even create a wifi network. I'd rather go for router + RPi combo. That way you will have reliable wifi network with decent range.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately my need was over a year. But I gave you the points for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an older flagship phone with 128gb or 256gb rom. install termux, ubuntu core and plone (cms).  this config has been functional for me for four years now.

i call this stack docudroid... set up time can take two hours because of python libraries.

Powertool for professors who wish to use (pre-downloaded) videos in classroom without relying on mobile data (for bandwidth challenged environments).